# Como fazer com que imagens fiquem ocupando 100% do browser

Tags: html, css, galeria, resolução-de-tela

Queria saber como faço para ter uma 'Galeria' tipo essa:(HTML e CSS)

http://logiciel-tek.com/demo/html/ether/ether-html/index.html  (Na area OUR WOKS)

Queria que ela ficase igual independente da resolução ou do zoom (igual a do exemplo), Que sempre a galeria ficase ocupando 100% da tela.  Se posivel coloque o codigo.

Comment: Olá, Existem plugins para browers que te deixam vasculhar o código dos sites que gostavas de saber como foram feitos. Eu por exemplo uso o firefox então tenho o Firebus. Basta clicares com o lado direito do rato sobre o que queres saber e escolher a opção para veres o tipo de código que queres. Podes escolher html, css, etc... Esse site usa html5. Até podem-te dizer como se faz mas se não tens as bases vais criar um site com erros grosseiros. Se me permites, nada melhor que aprenderes primeiro html5 e css3 antes de te aventurares.

Answer (score 4):

Coloquei o Css no mesmo arquivo que o html para Ficar mais Fácil a visualização 
Você pode fazer assim com uma image ou no background do Body para os dois o método é o mesmo.

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <style>
      .Imagem{
                    width: 100%;
                    height : 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;        
             }
    </style>
    </head>
   <body>
     <img src = "download.jpg" class = "Imagem"></img>
   </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: Para não falhar de forma alguma, defina que a largura minima da imagem seja (min-width:100%), assim quando a imagem for maior que o display exigido ela também ficará com a mesma proporção.